# Applying type: 'dark' to a MUI palette breaks my site unless it is defined directly in the createMuiTheme() function

Tags: reactjs, themes, material-ui, tsx

I am unable to define a 'dark' theme with MUI for my site when declaring `type: 'dark'` anywhere outside of the direct `createMuiTheme()` funciton.

For example, the following works:

```
const siteTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#484848',
      main: '#212121',
      dark: '#000000',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#b0ff57',
      main: '#76ff03',
      dark: '#32cb00',
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
    type: 'dark'
  },
})
```

But the following breaks:

```
const theme = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#484848',
      main: '#212121',
      dark: '#000000',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#b0ff57',
      main: '#76ff03',
      dark: '#32cb00',
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
    type: 'dark'
  },
}

const siteTheme = createMuiTheme(theme)
```

And the error it gives is

> 54 | const siteTheme = createMuiTheme(theme)
>
> Argument of type '{ palette: { primary: { light: string; main: string; dark: string; contrastText: string; }; secondary: { light: string; main: string; dark: string; contrastText: string; }; type: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThemeOptions'.
>     Types of property 'palette' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ primary: { light: string; main: string; dark: string; contrastText: string; }; secondary: { light: string; main: string; dark: string; contrastText: string; }; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PaletteOptions'.
>         Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
>           Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"dark" | "light" | undefined'.ts(2345)

I am using a `.tsx` file.

Why can I not define `type = 'dark'` outside of the direct `createMuiTheme()` function?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you are using TypeScript you need to make sure you cast it to the correct type:

```
import { PaletteType } from '@material-ui/core';

const theme = {
  palette: {
    type: 'dark' as PaletteType,
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that `PaletteType` seems to have been renamed to `PaletteMode`. `@material-ui/core/index.d.ts:50` - `export type PaletteMode = 'light' | 'dark';` This, in turn, means that the `type` key has, accordingly, been renamed to `mode`.

Comment: You saved me :)

Answer (score 6):

The naming seems to have changed since [@Farser's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61986784/3043260), so I am adding an updated answer in case somebody stumbles upon this question, as I did, in the future.

I found the following line at `@material-ui/core/index.d.ts:50`, so I assume that the authors have decided to rename the palette "type" to "mode":

```
export type PaletteMode = 'light' | 'dark';
```

Here is a minimal working example of an `App.tsx` (assuming the default `index.tsx` generated by `create-react-app` or similar):

```
import React from "react";
import { createMuiTheme, PaletteMode, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "dark" as PaletteMode
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className="App" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

As a side note, it should be also possible to use `useMediaQuery("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")` to determine whether the user prefers a dark or a light theme and automatically set the appropriate one like this:

```
mode: (useMediaQuery("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)") ? "dark" : "light") as PaletteMode
```

Another small addition/note: Don't forget to add `<CssBaseline />` at the top of the `<ThemeProvider>`, typically above your root element/component.

Comment: My imports only work like `import { ThemeProvider, createTheme, responsiveFontSizes} from '@mui/material/styles'; `